# Save Bag for Later in Magento 1.8?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

There is a default button - **Clear Shopping Bag** in Magento 1.8,

But I don't need this button, I need a button for '**Save Bag for Later**' - is it possible in Magento?

Below is the code from `frontend\mystore\default\template\checkout/cart.phtml`

```
<div class="row box-cart-control">
    <ul class="items-button-cart pull-right">
        <li class="col-lg-4"><button type="submit" name="update_cart_action" value="update_qty" title="<?php echo $this->__('Update Shopping Bag'); ?>" class="btn-update btn btn-primary button-cart-control"><?php echo $this->__('Update Shopping Bag'); ?></button></li>
        <?php if($this->getContinueShoppingUrl()): ?>
        <li class="col-lg-4"><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Continue Shopping') ?>" class="btn-continue btn btn-primary button-cart-control" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getContinueShoppingUrl() ?>')"><?php echo $this->__('Continue Shopping') ?></button></li>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <li class="col-lg-4"><button type="submit" name="update_cart_action" value="empty_cart" title="<?php echo $this->__('Clear Shopping Bag'); ?>" class="btn-empty btn btn-primary button-cart-control" id="empty_cart_button"><?php echo $this->__('Clear Shopping Bag'); ?></button></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What should I use for 'Save Bag for Later' to **replace** this below?

```
button type="submit" name="update_cart_action" value="empty_cart"
```

Comment: have you develop the functionality for save bag for later ?

Comment: No I haven't - I dunno how to. I just wonder if Magento 1.8 comes with this functionality or not.

Comment: no magento doenot come with this functionality. You can do achieve this by not let the cart empty after closing browser

Comment: do you want to save whole cart or also a particular products in cart for later

Comment: if you want to save the cart without doing any custom code, force the customers to login/register, the cart will be saved till they delete the products themselves. Otherwise how guests can retrieve their cart back, if you use IP, some may have dynamic ips, this will be overhead then.

Comment: Got it! I just thought of that too! :D